IBM Db2 for z/OS Developer Extension on Visual Studio Code V1.87.2
Before I go down the 'rabbit hole' of using IBM Db2 for z/OS Developer Extension on Visual Studio I have a question.  I currently use Datagrip for running SQL and making changes on our DB2 tables.  One of the features I enjoy is making direct changes to displayed table date and just hitting 'SUMMIT' to update the table directly without having to create any sql code.     I.e. I highlight a field, change the data in the field and then just 'SUBMIT' the change. It is a big time saver when you have to change a parameter flag real quick during a production issue.
Tried going to Table:xxxxxx and 'Data' tab and directly edit results as well as trying to edit results from a SQL Select results.

Are you asking how to make one tool behave like a different tool ?

Not sure entirely what the question is, but I think you are asking if the Db2 developer extension in VSCode has the ability to edit tables via a GUI?
As far as I am aware it doesn't. You'd need to do it via writing/generating and running SQL.
I'm curious why you'd want to go down the rabbit whole as you say given that you already appear to have a tool that gives you the functionality you want? Datagrip is probably a larger and more full fledged product than any VSCode extension will ever be able to be and I'm sure your company is paying a pretty penny for it, so might as well use it if you can.
